# Differential characterization of monotone operators

Tags: differential, monotone-operator-theory

Given $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. $f:D\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be a **monotone operator** if 
$$\left\langle f(x)-f(y),x-y\right\rangle\ge 0,\text{ for all }x,y\in D.$$
I wonder if this hypothesis is true about monotone operators.

Given $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a differentiable operator   $f:D\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, two following statements are equivalent

(i) $f$ is a monotone operator.

(ii) $\left\langle u,f'(x)(u)\right\rangle\ge 0$ for all $x\in D$ and $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Can you show me the proof (or brief proof) if this is true or show me the counterexample if this is false?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $D$ is convex. You can use the mean value theorem, applied to the auxiliary function 
$$
h(t)=f(y+t(x-y)).
$$
In terms of $h$ condition (i) reads $\langle h(1)-h(0),x-y\rangle\ge 0$
If $f$ is differentiable, so is $h$ and, by the mean value theorem
$$
h(1)-h(0)=h'(\xi)=f'(z)(x-y)
$$
where $0<\xi<1$ and, equivalently, $z$ is in the segment joining $x$ and $y$. Then, your inequality certainly holds if
$$
\langle f'(z)(x-y),x-y\rangle\ge 0
$$ 
for all $x,y\in D$ and all $z\in D$, which is implied by (ii). For the necessity, you can argue by contradiction, showing that if condition $(ii)$ fails, you can choose a point $y$ close to $x$ in the direction of $u$ such that inequality $(i)$ is violated (just by linear approximation).

Comment: Thank you for your support. However, you used *Mean value theorem** for h function, which is a **vector-valued function** but Wikipedia said that **Mean value theorem** cannot be applied for this type of function. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem